# retrieve values from firestore's struct in swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm querying some data from my firestore,and I put it in my Usersdata,
but I dont know how to get my values from Usersdata.

Please help me to query my data!

This is my struct base on Firestroe example

```
struct Usersdata {
let uid:String?
let facebook:String?
let google:String?
let name:String?
let age:Int?
let birthday:String?
let smokeage:Int?
let smokeaddiction:Int?
let smokebrand:String?
let gold:Int?
let score:Int?
let fish:Int?
let shit:Int?
let userimage:String?
init?(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
    guard let uid = dictionary["uid"] as? String else { return nil }
    self.uid = uid
    self.facebook = dictionary["facebook"] as? String
    self.google = dictionary["google"] as? String
    self.name = dictionary["name"] as? String
    self.age = dictionary["age"] as? Int
    self.birthday = dictionary["birthday"] as? String
    self.smokeage = dictionary["smokeage"] as? Int
    self.smokeaddiction = dictionary["smokeaddiction"] as? Int
    self.smokebrand = dictionary["smokebrand"] as? String
    self.gold = dictionary["gold"] as? Int
    self.score = dictionary["score"] as? Int
    self.fish = dictionary["fish"] as? Int
    self.shit = dictionary["shit"] as? Int
    self.userimage = dictionary["userimage"] as? String
    }   
}
```

this is my function to query data from firebase

```
 func test(schema:String , collection:String , document : String){
    let queryRef = db.collection("Users").document(userID).collection(collection).document(document)
    queryRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let user = document.flatMap({
            $0.data().flatMap({ (data) in
                return Usersdata(dictionary: data)
            })
        }) {
            print("Success \(user)")
        } else {
            print("Document does not exist")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are asking how to work with a structure with Firebase data. Here's a solution that will read in a known user, populate a structure with that data and then print the uid and name.

Assume a stucture

```
Users
  uid_0
    name: "Henry"
```

and then a structure to hold that data

```
struct Usersdata {
    let uid:String?
    let user_name:String?
    init(aDoc: DocumentSnapshot) {
        self.uid = aDoc.documentID
        self.user_name = aDoc.get("name") as? String ?? ""
    }
}
```

and a function to read that user, populate the struct and print out data from the struct

```
func readAUser() {
    let docRef = self.db.collection("Users").document("uid_0")
    docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let document = document, document.exists {
            let aUser = Usersdata(aDoc: document)
            print(aUser.uid, aUser.user_name)
        } else {
            print("Document does not exist")
        }
    }
}
```

and the output

```
uid_0 Henry
```

Comment: thanks for your response , but I need to print (aUser) in another func.  Are there any solution to do this?

Comment: @Gary Not sure I understand that question.. you can just pass aUser like any other var.  So where the print statement is call the function *self.someOtherFunction(myUser: aUser)*

Comment: can you teach me how to declare a var user in global variable
 to pass aUser ?   sorry my english expression ability is not good

Comment: I got it !!  Thank you very much . Jay

Comment: Jay, can I ask you a last question. If I want to update values to Firestore with the struct , how can I do?

Comment: @Gary Sure - I would first refer the guide [Firestore: add a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document). Once you have a populated struct you can directly access it's properties; *let userName = aUser.user_name* for example. Then you can use the code from the guide to create a document and add data; from the example: *addDocument(data: "name": [ "Tokyo"* would be *addDocument(data: "name": [userName*