# update values from struct to Firestore in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to update values from struct,This is my struct code.

```
struct Usersdata {
let uid:String?
let facebook:String?
let google : String?
let name : String?
let age : Int?
let birthday : String?
let smokeage  : Int?
let smokeaddiction : Int?
let smokebrand  : String?
let gold : Int?
let score : Int?
let fish : Int?
let shit : Int?
let userimage  : String?
init(aDoc: DocumentSnapshot) {
    self.uid = aDoc.get("uid") as? String ?? ""
    self.facebook = aDoc.get("facebook") as? String ?? ""
    self.google = aDoc.get("google") as? String ?? ""
    self.name = aDoc.get("name") as? String ?? ""
    self.age = aDoc.get("age") as? Int ?? 0
    self.birthday = aDoc.get("birthday") as? String ?? ""
    self.smokeage = aDoc.get("smokeage") as? Int ?? 0
    self.smokeaddiction = aDoc.get("smokeaddiction") as? Int ?? 0
    self.smokebrand = aDoc.get("smokebrand") as? String ?? ""
    self.gold = aDoc.get("gold") as? Int ?? 0
    self.score = aDoc.get("score") as? Int ?? 0
    self.fish = aDoc.get("fish") as? Int ?? 0
    self.shit = aDoc.get("shit") as? Int ?? 0
    self.userimage = aDoc.get("userimage") as? String ?? ""
    }
}
```

I got values from my query func like this

```
func queryAUser() {
    let docRef = self.db.collection("Users").document(userID).collection("userdata").document("userdata")
    docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let document = document, document.exists {
            let aUser = Usersdata(aDoc: document)
            self.local_userdata = aUser
        } else {
            print("Document does not exist")
        }
    }
}
```

I can use local_userdata to get my values , but I want to update new values to Firestore now .

Are there any solutions to update values from Usersdata.struct?

Comment: You mean to get only the changes in `Usersdata` and update the firestore document?

Comment: For reference, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52973289/retrieve-values-from-firestores-struct-in-swift/52975701#52975701) which provides some background. I think my last comment to the answer may be an answer to this question? Can you clarify what you're asking? Are you asking how to read the properties of a structure or how to write data to FireStore?

Comment: I need to change Userdata values and update it . For example, I want to make local.uid= "00001"  and local.userdata.name = "Gary"  , and let this two values update to firestore together .  Does it can work?

Comment: @Jay , Your answer is really help me alot . But I need to change local_userdata values in another function and update it  .  Under the premise , I don't know what field will be change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me give this a shot.

Assuming you have read in a user using the code in your question and the user is stored in self.local_userdata

Here's an example function to update a users name given a users uid and a new name

```
func updateUserName(withUid: String, toNewName: String) {
    self.db.collection("users").document(withUid).setData( ["name": toNewName], merge: true)
}
```

To use this, read self.local_userdata.uid so we know which user we want to modify and pass in that uid and what the new name should be.

You could enhance this further to update any field for a certain user with this

```
func updateUserField(withUid: String, andField: String, toNewValue: String) {
    self.db.collection("users").document(withUid).setData( [andField: toNewValue], merge: true)
}
```

of course if you are changing the fields you should also update the structure accordingly

self.local_userdata.name = "some name"